# Create spreadsheet using Google Spreadsheets API in Google Drive

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I have successfully created a new worksheet in an existing spreadsheet of My Google Drive account through a simple Java code mentioned in Google's official documentation on Developer Guide Sheets API but want to create a new spreadsheet in my Google Drive account through Java code. In the link they didn't mention any sample code for that. I have already seen different methods available in Spreadservice class.

How to do this with Google Spreadsheets API?

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.data.Link;
import com.google.gdata.data.PlainTextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.TextConstruct;
import com.google.gdata.data.docs.ExportFormat;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.*;
import com.google.gdata.util.*;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.soap.Text;


    /**
     *
     * @author satyam
     */
    public class SpreadSheet {

        public static void main(String[] args)
                throws AuthenticationException, MalformedURLException, IOException, ServiceException {

            SpreadsheetService service =   new SpreadsheetService("gBuddy");

            // TODO: Authorize the service object for a specific user (see other sections)
            String USERNAME = "USERNAME";
            String PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

            service.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);


            // Define the URL to request.  This should never change.
            URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(
                    "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full");

            // Make a request to the API and get all spreadsheets.
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
            List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();

            // Iterate through all of the spreadsheets returned
            for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet : spreadsheets) {
    //             Print the title of this spreadsheet to the screen;
                System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());
            }

            SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = spreadsheets.get(1);
    //        System.out.println(spreadsheet.getTitle().getPlainText());

    //        // Create a local representation of the new worksheet.
            WorksheetEntry worksheet = new WorksheetEntry();
            worksheet.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("New Worksheet"));
            worksheet.setColCount(10);
            worksheet.setRowCount(20);

            // Send the local representation of the worksheet to the API for
            // creation.  The URL to use here is the worksheet feed URL of our
            // spreadsheet.
            URL worksheetFeedUrl = spreadsheet.getWorksheetFeedUrl();
            WorksheetEntry insert = service.insert(worksheetFeedUrl, worksheet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's just simple after some research I found this answer. We cannot create a new spreadsheet in google drive with **Google Spreadsheet API**.

**NOTE:** we can create new worksheet in already exist spreadsheet of google drive through Google Spreadsheet API but cannot create a new spreadsheet with spreadsheet api.

For creating and uploading new Spreadsheet or any other kind of document which google drive supports we have to use **Google Drive api**.

This is what I am looking for. By this we can create a new spreadsheet in google drive using google drive api.

```
    DocsService docsService = new DocsService("MySampleApplication-v3");
    docsService.setUserCredentials(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    URL GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/");
    DocumentListEntry documentListEntry = new com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry();
    documentListEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Spreadsheet_name"));
    documentListEntry = docsService.insert(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL, documentListEntry);
```

For creating a new spreadsheet we have to create `new SpreadsheetEntry()` object and for any other document we have to create `new DocumentEntry()` object.

NOW If we have to upload any kind of document(xls,doc,image etc) in google drive we can do like this

```
//File upload in google drive
        DocumentListEntry uploadFile = new DocumentListEntry();
        uploadFile.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("FILE_NAME_DISPLAY_IN_DRIVE"));
        uploadFile.setFile(new File("FILE_PATH"), "MIME_TYPE_OF_FILE");
        uploadFile = docsService.insert(GOOGLE_DRIVE_FEED_URL, uploadFile);
```

Comment: But how do you deal with this error? `com.google.gdata.util.InvalidEntryException: Entry must contain exactly one primary category`

Comment: Had to use fully qualified package name. There are TWO SpreadsheetEntry classes. WTF Google? `entry.getCategories().add(com.google.gdata.data.docs.SpreadsheetEntry.CATEGORY);`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) to create new speadsheets.

> What can this API do?
>
> The Google Documents List API allows developers to create, retrieve,
>   update, and delete Google Docs (including but not limited to text
>   documents, spreadsheets, presentations, and drawings), files, and
>   collections. It also provides some advanced features like resource
>   archives, Optical Character Recognition, translation, and revision
>   history.

Comment: I already checked this link but how to do in java as there is sample code in .NET not in java. Even i tried to find same class in java api but not successful.

Comment: Unfortunately, this API has been deprecated. You should use the [google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive)